# Find the sides of a triangle knowing only hypotenuse and right angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to find the area of a molecule and I know a bond angle of a right angle, but need to know the the other sides in order to calculate area. Is this even possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the area of a molecule?

Comment: I'm trying to find the cross sectional area of phenol. It's a benzene ring with an alcohol attached. It's a mix of chemistry and geometry.

Comment: David, but phenol has each interior angle $\approx 120^{\circ}$ , similar to a  regular hexagon.Which angle are you exactly talking about? You can elaborate, I know a bit chemistry too :D

Comment: I didnt know that about the interior angle. I'm trying to work it so I can find the maximum extinction. I was talking a double bond with the bond length of 134 pm to find if I drew a line across from where the alcohol comes off to the other side. Thus giving me the total length from the alcohol to the other end for the length of a rectangle.

So I take the hexagon and break it down into pieces and I have 4 triangles and 2 squares. With Phenol it's not an exact hexagon since the sides aren't all the same.

Comment: Thank you Jaideep Khare. Your interior angle helped me figure it out. Benzene rings have all have a bond length of 140pm.